# Mouse buttons wrong reaction

Tags: linux, mouse-click

When click on right click system register that as ESC+F5, middle click registers first ESC then F5 in turn. What can help to fix that.
Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.